# Functions for searching through strings

Tags: python, string

[image]I need some help to write 2 functions for a program. It should return true/false value if the characters in str(word) are also in the str(string).
The results should look like this:

```
find_indices("esimerkki", "esmerki")
    (True, [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8])

find_indices("iiiieeee", "ieeiiee")
    (False, [0, 4, 5])

find_indices("iiiieeee", "iieee")
    (True, [0, 1, 4, 5, 6])
```

How to proceed? The second funtion should be easy as long as the first one is complete, but I don't know how to start the first one.

```
     def find_indices(string, word):
            """
            returns the first indices in 'string' that form (in order) the substring 'word'
            
            returns True, list of indices 
            - if all of the letters in 'word' were found in order
            
            returns False, list of indices as far as matches were found 
            - if none or only some of the letters in 'word' were found in order
            
            e.g.
            
            > find_indices("esimerkki", "sei")
            > (True, [1, 4, 8])
            
            > find_indices("esimerkki", "side")
            > (False, [1, 2])
            """
            # implement your code here!
        
        def find_indices_ignore_case(string, word):
            """
            finds the indices of 'word' in 'string in order - exactly like in 'find_indices', 
            except the case of the letters is ignored
            """
            # implement your code here!
            
        def main():
            # examples to test your functions
            example_cases = ( \
                ("esimerkki", ""), 
                ("esimerkki", "sei"), 
                ("esimerkki", "kis"), 
                ("iiiieeee", "iieee"), 
                ("iiiieeee", "iei"), 
                ("iiiieeee", "ieeiiee"), 
                ("esimerkki", "esmerki"), 
                ("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "ohjelmointi"), 
                ("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit", "on ohjelmointi on 
                 kivaa"), 
                ("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit", "meri")
                )
            for example_string, example_word in example_cases:
                print("find_indices('{:s}', '{:s}') \nreturned {}\n".format(example_string, 
                example_word, find_indices(example_string, example_word)))
            
            print('find_indices("EsIMERKKITEKSTI", "SeiTi") \nreturned', 
                  find_indices("EsIMERKKITEKSTI", "SeiTi"))
            print('\nfind_indices_ignore_case("EsIMERKKITEKSTI", "SeiTi") \nreturned', 
                  find_indices_ignore_case("EsIMERKKITEKSTI", "SeiTi"))
            
        main()
```

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

There is an approach:

```
def find_indices(string, word):
    iter_s = enumerate(string)
    indices = []
    for c1 in word:
        ind = next((i for i, c2 in iter_s if c1 == c2), None)
        if ind is None:            
            return False, indices
        indices.append(ind)
    return True, indices

>>> find_indices("esimerkki", "esmerki")
(True, [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8])
>>> find_indices("esimerkki", "side")
(False, [1, 2])
>>> find_indices("esimerkki", "")
(True, [])
>>> find_indices("esimerkki", "sei")
(True, [1, 4, 8])
>>> find_indices("esimerkki", "kis")
(False, [6, 8])
```

`iter_s` is an iterator over the (index, character) pairs in `string`. This lazy iterator can only move forward. As you iterate through the word (`for c1 in word`), you move `iter_s` ahead until you hit a match (`ind = next((... for i, c2 in iter_s ...), default)`). If no such match is found (`if ind is None`), you can immediately return the negative result with the indeces you found until that point.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried to run it, but it only returned:

Comment: find_indices('esimerkki', '') 
returned None

find_indices('esimerkki', 'sei') 
returned None

find_indices('esimerkki', 'kis') 
returned None

Comment: Are you sure you did not forget to copy the last line of the function body? I added those examples and they definitely work.

Comment: I added a picture to the original post. Do I maybe need to do something with the main function?